# Manipulating .eps format images

Tags: c#, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm working on a C# project and I need guidance on

1. How to convert .eps file format to .bmp using ghostscript, `ImageMagik`,
2. Without using ghostscript, `ImageMagik` how can I check for colors in the image(.eps)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use Ghostscript wrapper for **.NET**. You can find one here: [**Ghostscript.NET on GitHub**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET)

To get ink coverage you can check out this sample: [**Ghostscript.NET.Samples.GetInkCoverage**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/GetInkCoverageSample.cs)

Comment: tried your suggestion and i know i am going in the right direction but i get this error An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -15 do you know how to work around that

Comment: @vjalex: -15 means 'rangecheck' error. If you could post your code here, it would be helpful to determine where the problem is. At the first look, this error sounds like you are passing bad parameter...

Comment: yours is the appropriate answer to the question but i am newbie and can u please tell me how to use your suggestions i want to just rasterize the image using the ghostscript dll

Comment: thanks for your answer the problem was with loading the dll from memory or disk

Answer (score 0):

1. Using [Magick.NET](http://magick.codeplex.com/) try the following.

   ```
   using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("myImage.eps"))
   {
      image.Write("myImage.bmp");
   }
   ```
2. Why without ghostscript? If you have converted the image already, then use the bmp and iterate through the pixels as normal. If you cant use an outside library, then you'll have to write your functions to convert `.eps` files.

Comment: when using above code stackoverflow exception occurs .cannot read the eps image

Comment: without using ghostscript i meant is there any other simple way